# Pandas Update Data frame Julian Date Column to 'yyyy-MM-dd'

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe containing a column with julian date example: 16003 meaning 2016-01-03
I need to update the column values containing julian dates to "yyyy-mm-dd" format.

I found the below for conversion but i need it to be done on the whole data frame.

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.strptime('16234', '%y%j').date()
date = datetime.datetime.strptime('16234', '%y%j').date()
date.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [`pd.to_datetime()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with `format`.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['16234', '16003']})

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%y%j')
```

```
print(df)

        Date
0 2016-08-21
1 2016-01-03
```